# How cache index in MySQL actually works

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, myisam

I have a query which joins 10+ tables to create a new table. All tables are using MyISAM engine. I would like to create 4 tables at the same time using the same query, except change the first driven table.

I noticed that when I cache index the largest table there is a  performance gain, however if I cache index all tables the performance does not change. Also the documents say that after cache index you may want to load index into cache to preload the table's index into the RAM, but I did not achieve any performance gain on doing that. What's worse, preloading the index costs time.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `MyISAM`?

Comment: Generally: `cache index` is only useful if you can assign memory to indexes better than MySQL would do it by default; for a one(four)-time run, it rarely is. Also: what FrankerZ said. For your specific question, there are many details missing: one query and the execution plan (`explain select ...`): your indexes might simply not help that query. How did you measure performance gain/compared it to what? The indexes might e.g. already have been cached. Your index sizes, the `cache index`-sizes and the (general) keybuffer size? Adding caches may simply cover up a low default setting.

Comment: The reason why using *MyISAM* is because we simply use read only hence MyISAM is suppose to do a better work. I have attached the execution plan and perhaps not all indexes were used properly. The way that I measure the performance is I run the same 4 queries simultaneously and record their relative processing time. Then I use cache index to cache one of the largest table and run the same 4 queries again, and in this round I can see that all the time reduces.

Comment: I test by setting the key_buffer_size from 16M to 16G and there is not much difference. My AWS Server has 32GB RAM and expand to 128GB when increasing the key_buffer_size to 16G.

Comment: I doubt that you are measuring the effect of `cache index` (but probably just of *a* cache). Is `ctrl` in this example the biggest table? It doesn't use an indexes, so `cache index` cannot have an effect. Repeat your experiment, but don't do anything to the cache this time. This should be the baseline to compare the effect to. If it's faster too on the second run, it's not an effect of `cache index`. Btw, the objective key-index-related value is [`key_reads`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Key_reads), compare it for runs with/without `cache index`.

Comment: In general, I think your query is just slow, and your second run just takes advantage of it being already in cache. While I cannot tell you if it can be improved, your explain plan certainly doesn't look clean at all, so I would check your query before trying to micromanage the cache. You can ask for help here, but for a probably 100-line-with-15-joins-and-extensive-subqueries-query it's hard to find someone willing to take the time to look at it, so you may need to identify the biggest problems (and remove the clearly-non-improvable parts) to simplify your query, and provide sqlfiddle.

Comment: Actually the `ctrl` is the smallest table to drive the query. I conduct the experiment by first running the query without using the `cache index` then I restart the MySQL server, run the `cache index` for the second run. In this case, I dont think the second run would take the advantage of the first run and the second run does reduce some time. After using the `cache index`, the *key_reads* drops as well. I understand that the query is a bit complex and maybe too difficult to debug so really appreciate!

Comment: As I said: execute whatever you do as the experiment (here: server restart), but do not use `cache index` for the second run, to get the baseline/compare it to your current result. MyISAM is e.g. using the os file cache to cache data, so this might still be just a caching advantage. Also: make sure that `key_buffer_size` for the non-cache-index run is the original size plus the size of all your `cache index`es. Otherwise, "cache index" might just assign more cache to the server (which is better than not having enough cache) - but increasing `key_index_size` would have a similar effect.

Comment: I still doubt using `cache index` (without preload, or at least if you include the time to preload in your measurements) will have any positive effect in your setup, if you make sure you assign equal amount of total cache size. If it does, break it down to actual measurements (time and key_reads, and list index sizes) and describe the setup, e.g. `restart, execute, get time x0, key_reads, index sizes, restart, no cache index, execute, get time y0, key_reads, index_sizes; restart, execute, get time x1, ..., restart, cache index, execute, time y1, ...`.

Comment: Alright. I did try with restart, execute, get time and collect other records and restart the server to test the `cache index` magic, still cannot get a clue though. And we just spoke with Oracle MySQL technical expert that `MyisAM` cannot support more than 8 concurrent threads and it has come to its life. We will now switch our engine to Innodb and experiment the multi threads processing. Thanks

Comment: While it is tempting to take over the micromanaging of caching, it is usually wasted effort.  You would be better off moving to InnoDB and tuning it.  (key_buffer_size = 40M, innodb_buffer_pool_size = 70% of RAM; the rest _probably_ won't matter).

Comment: Using composite indexes, reformulating queries, and using Summary tables are (often) _the most_ productive ways to improve performance (whether MyISAM or InnoDB).  Sometimes I see 10-fold improvement.  Such is rarely available from tuning.